# Need a string with double quote immediately followed by single quote in python 2.6

Tags: python, string, python-2.6

I am trying to store a string in variable `A` which contains:

```
"'D:\\Work\\B1.tif';'D:\\Work\\B2.tif'"
```

I have two variables that store the locations of `B1.tif` and `B2.tif`:

```
X = "D:\\Work\\B1.tif"
Y = "D:\\Work\\B2.tif"
```

However, when I try to combine all the strings into a variable 'A':

```
A = '"' + "'" + X + "'" + ";" + "'" + Y + "'" + '"'
```

This is what it stores as:

```
'"\'D:\\Work\\B1.tif\';\'D:\\Work\\B2.tif\'"'
```

When I `print` `A` it displays:

```
"'D:\Work\B1.tif';'D:\Work\B2.tif'"
```

It seems that a backslash (`\`), that separates double quotes (`"`) and single quotes (`"`), are automatically stored in the string. How do I store double quotes and single quotes in a string without the backslash separating the quotes?

Comment: Please don't post links to images, the text cannot be copied easily into test code.

Comment: use string formating instead of concatenation

Comment: print '"\'%s\';\'%s\'"' %(X,Y)

Answer (score 2):

String formatting (and raw strings) is much easier:

```
A = "\"'D:\\Work\\B1.tif';'D:\\Work\\B1.tif'\""
print A

X = r"D:\Work\B1.tif" 
Y = r"D:\Work\B2.tif"

A = '"' + "'" + X + "'" + ";" + "'" + Y + "'" + '"'
print A

A = "\"'%s';'%s'\"" % (X, Y)
print A
```

Gives:

```
"'D:\Work\B1.tif';'D:\Work\B1.tif'"
"'D:\Work\B1.tif';'D:\Work\B2.tif'"
"'D:\Work\B1.tif';'D:\Work\B2.tif'"
```

However, to get the results you show, you have to use `repr()`, which is what IDLE uses if you just type the variable name in.  If I change all the `print` statements to `print repr(A)` I get:

```
'"\'D:\\Work\\B1.tif\';\'D:\\Work\\B1.tif\'"'
'"\'D:\\Work\\B1.tif\';\'D:\\Work\\B2.tif\'"'
'"\'D:\\Work\\B1.tif\';\'D:\\Work\\B2.tif\'"'
```

IDLE uses the class's `__repr__()` method, `print` uses `__str__()`.  Often they are the same, but sometime, as here, they are not.

Answer (score 2):

print '"\'%s\';\'%s\'"' %(X,Y)

Answer (score 1):

When you display a variable in Python by just typing it's name, Python tries to print it in a way that if you were to copy and paste it as a variable, it would produce the same object. This works for strings, lists, dictionaries, sets, etc. The consequence is that strings need to be escaped when printed out this way. The backlashes are not actually stored in the string. You can see that by calculating the length:

```
>>> a = '"' + "'"
>>> a
'"\''
>>> len(a)
2
>>> print a
"'
```

There are, however, better ways to build the same string you want, as shown by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.format()` for these complicated formatting situations, you can even use triple quoted strings to make it easier.

```
A = ''' "'{}';'{}'" '''.format(X,Y)
```